# Is Amazon RDS Backup sufficient or should you do your own as well?

Tags: database-backups, amazon-rds

I've been using Amazon RDS for a while now, and supplementing the automated backups with my own mysqldump backup routine that copies the sql dump to a remote (not AWS) server.

The mysqldump causes server load to spike, though, and is generally a resource hog. I'd like to get rid of it if I can.

The native RDS automated backup routine seems pretty robust and reliable, as far as I can tell. Is my (less-efficient, more management-intensive) redundant routine necessary, or am I just being paranoid?

FWIW, the data is mission critical, in the sense that losing all (or most) of it would be catastrophic to the organization. However, losing a small amount of data (e.g., 5-10 minutes worth), would not be too terrible.

Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth RDS backups are 'smart' - they only store deltas so can go wrong - last summer a bug resulting in a number of snapshots being lost. Since then I've kept 'dumb' gzipped dumps elsewhere. I avoid impact on the production db by restoring the snapshots res creates nightly to a new instance and run mysqldump against that.